# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<int>' in type cast while trying to retrive bluetooth state in flutter

Tags: flutter, iot, flutter-getx

[See error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPQ3A.png)

I'm trying to monitor the state of the bluetooth device. For example a users bluetooth is turned on before entering the app. I want the bluetooth swtich to be turned on in the app. I am using GetX for state management

```
BluetoothState bluetoothState = BluetoothState.UNKNOWN;
 Future<void> enableBluetooth() async {
// Retrieving the current Bluetooth state
      bluetoothState = await 
FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.state.;
// If the bluetooth is off, then turn it on first
// and then retrieve the devices that are paired.
if (bluetoothState == BluetoothState.STATE_OFF) {
  await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.requestEnable();
  await getPairedDevices();
  return true;
} else {
  await getPairedDevices();
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Show the ```bluetoothState```declaration.

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Does BluetoothState<dynamic> solve the problem?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full stacktrace? (in the debug console, everything that starts with `E/flutter`)